# How to give a site a side scroll bar when resizing window instead of allowing all elements to bundle or stack up together?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a site where i have given the elements static widths and heights. The website also includes images. When i resize the window, all the elements bundle up together (for example, in full window mode there are 3 images in a line whereas when I resize the window only 1 image is shown per line). Also all other elements get stacked up on each other. I wanted to know how can I prevent this and let all the elements in the same order as they are when in full window by giving it a side scroll bar on the bottom. For reference, see the Facebook login page: [facebook login page](https://www.facebook.com/). You might need to logout.

When you resize it, it simply gives a side scroll bar on the bottom and all elements remain in the same order. Is it possible to do this just with HTML or CSS or do I have to use JavaScript. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you provide us with relevant code (code that could be a possible reason for this error)? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying the following Css:

```
body {
  min-width: 1280px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Just replace the pixel value with the required width.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the width of the body fixed to a specific px (the width of your window), for 1000px example

```css
body {
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `overflow-x: scroll;` or `overflow-x: auto;` to the body, that should do the trick. Also don't forget to add a `min-width` and `max-width` as well to make it take effect.